# How to open a file in the parent directory in python in AppEngine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

How to open a file in the parent directory in python in AppEngine?

I have a python file module/mod.py with the following code

```
f = open('../data.yml')
z = yaml.load(f)
f.close()
```

data.yml is in the parent dir of module. The error I get is

```
IOError: [Errno 13] file not accessible: '../data.yml'
```

I am using AppEngine SDK 1.3.3.

Is there a work around for this?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

The `open` function operates relative to the current process working directory, not the module it is called from. If the path must be module-relative, do this:

```
import os.path
f = open(os.path.dirname(__file__) + '/../data.yml')
```

Comment: In my opinion, it would be better if, instead of concatenating the filename, you used "os.path.join"

For instance:  
    open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), os.pardir, 'data.yml'))

Comment: Yes. But make sure to use \__file\__ instead of file

Comment: Alternatively, make sure to wrap `code` in back-quotes.

Comment: This doesnt work for me. It looks for a path with /../ component. Error is FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/brownie/scripts/../brownie-config.yml'

Answer (score 11):

Having encountered this question and not being satisfied with the answer, I ran across a different solution.  It took the following to get what I wanted.

1. Determine the current directory using `os.path.dirname`:

   `current_directory = os.path.dirname(__file__)`
2. Determine the parent directory using `os.path.split`:

   `parent_directory = os.path.split(current_directory)[0] # Repeat as needed`
3. Join parent_directory with any sub-directories:

   `file_path = os.path.join(parent_directory, 'path', 'to', 'file')`
4. Open the file:

   `open(file_path)`

Combined together:

```
open(os.path.join(os.path.split(os.path.dirname(__file__))[0], 'path', 'to', 'file')
```

Answer (score 5):

*alternative solution*

You can also use the `sys` module to get the current working directory.
Thus, another alternative to do the same thing would be:

```
import sys
f = open(sys.path[0] + '/../data.yml')
```

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a little function called get_parent_directory() which might help getting the path of the parent directory:

```
import sys
def get_parent_directory():
    list = sys.path[0].split('/')[:-1]
    return_str = ''
    for element in list:
        return_str += element + '/'
    return return_str.rstrip('/')
```

Comment: It is more correct to use `os.path.dirname` or similar specialized functions and doesn't reinvent them by yourself. Also more correct way to join strings will be `'/'.join(list)`

Answer (score 0):

@ThatsAmorais answer in a function

```
import os

def getParent(path: str, levels=1) -> str:
    """
    @param path: starts without /
    @return: Parent path at the specified levels above.
    """
    current_directory = os.path.dirname(__file__)

    parent_directory = current_directory
    for i in range(0, levels):
        parent_directory = os.path.split(parent_directory)[0]

    file_path = os.path.join(parent_directory, path)
    return file_path
```