# Google App Engine No such file or directory:

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm trying to deploy a project to Google App Engine. The main HTML page I render is stored in the /documents/form.html directory of the project. If I run on my local host it finds the file no problem. When I deploy to GAE it gives the below error:

```
File "/base/data/home/apps/s~andesonchase/1.372703354720880550/main.py", line 4, in <module>
    fileHandle = open("documents/form.html", "r")
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'documents/form.html'
```

I think I need to include it on my app.yaml but I'm not sure on the correct syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can list three options for you

A) as suggested by the previous poster is to add to [app.yaml](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Python_app_yaml_Static_file_handlers) as either a static_files entry or by making documents a static_dir which would allow access to the files using raw http requests but completely bypassing your handlers in main.py

B) [probably the most kosha] is to access the file with the jinja2 template library [as explained here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/templates) which doesn't require you to add the files explicitly to app.yaml

C) or you could stick with whatever your doing inside main.py at the moment but modify your open statement as follows

```
import os.path
f = open(os.path.dirname(__file__) + '/documents/form.html')
```

as explained in [this stackoverlflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2753254/how-to-open-a-file-in-the-parent-directory-in-python-in-appengine) since open works a little differently with appengine

Answer (score 0):

If you want to serve it as a static file add it like this:

Add it to your app.yaml and replace `/form` with the url you please

```
- url: /form
  static_files: documents/form.html
  upload: documents/form.html
```

If you need to run a script then it's different.