# Connect to SQLite database in web app

Tags: python, google-app-engine, sqlite

I am trying to connect to a database object I created for use in a web app.

The python code for the app is the following:

```
import os
import jinja2
import webapp2
import sqlite3
#from google.appengine.ext import db

template_dir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'templates')
jinja_env = jinja2.Environment(loader = jinja2.FileSystemLoader(template_dir), autoescape = True)

class Handler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def write(self, *a, **kw):
        self.response.out.write(*a,**kw)

    def render_str(self, template, **params):
        t = jinja_env.get_template(template)
        return t.render(params)

    def render(self, template, **kw):
        self.write(self.render_str(template, **kw))

#class bars_data():
#    def createdb(self):
        #barsdb = sqlite3.connect('bardatabase.db')
        #barsdb.execute("DROP TABLE if exists bars")
        #barsdb.execute("create table bars(name text, address text, state int)")
        #barsdb.execute('Insert into bars (name, address, state) VALUES(?,?,?)',("Hoolies", '24 Glebe Rd', 10))
        #barsdb.execute('Insert into bars (name, address, state) VALUES(?,?,?)',("Bar1", '25 Main St', 10))
        #barsdb.execute('Insert into bars (name, address, state) VALUES(?,?,?)',('Cafe Doug', '35 Summer St.', 5))
        #barsdb.execute('Insert into bars (name, address, state) VALUES(?,?,?)',("McMurphy", '25 F Street', 20))
        #barsdb.commit()       

class MainPage(Handler):
    def get(self):
        barsdb = sqlite3.connect('bardatabase.db')
        query = barsdb.cursor()
        bars_list = barsdb.execute("SELECT name FROM barsdb")

        self.render("index.html")

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainPage)
], debug=True)
```

I used the code in "class bars_data()" to originally create the data base file which is in the same directory as the rest of the source code files but since I do not run it with the app I commented it out.  I am not sure if I need to recreate the database/table when I run the app so included it if this is the case.  I want to access the bar names from the database and write it to the page using jinja.

I am using the Google App Engine to run it.  I know I could use the data store but this seemed an easier way to create a static database.

When I try to run the app nothing will render.  But when I remove the code tyring to make the database connection my "index.html" template will again render in the browser.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you obtain traceback somehow? Enable debugging mode or wrap the code into try-catch and render traceback. I have no experience with GAE, but I would say you shouldn't store data to files (including sqlite3) given the distributed nature of the platform... See here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2693092/196206 But maybe something changed since then.

Comment: This can't possibly work. GAE apps can not write to the filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

If you are providing the database file as a part of the application files this should work. Just make sure the file path is correct as mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2753304/202775). Do not assume the application's working directory and the data directory are the same.