# Why can't my Python program find my file?

Tags: python, file-io, runtime-error

Note: I’m using Windows and this program will also have to run on Mac.

I'm writing a Python app that needs to read from and write to a JSON file, which I implemented in `src/resources.py`:

```
import json
def load_json():
    with open('saved_data.json', 'rt') as file_in:
        stored_text = file_in.read()
    stored_json = json.loads(stored_text)
    # parse stored_json & return created objects
```

At the beginning of the program it's supposed to load data from the file, but when I run `main.py` (where I’m usually running the program from) it's giving me a runtime error:

```
File "<project path>\src\resources.py", line 12, in load_json
    with open('saved_data.json', 'rt') as file_in:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'saved_data.json'
```

This is what my file structure looks like:

```
project/
    main.py
    saved_data.json
    src/
        __init__.py
        resources.py
        more files...
```

I've tried adding either `'..\\'` or `'../'` to the start of the filepath string thinking that it might be relative to resources.py instead of main.py but that resulted in an error as well. I'm not really sure what to do at this point because I don't see anywhere specific it could be going wrong. I'm *pretty* sure the file structure is okay. What am I missing or misunderstanding here?

Comment: '../' should be fine. Does it give the same error or a different one? What OS are you using (not sure if it matter though)?

Comment: using above suggestion, possible duplicate or helpful https://stackoverflow.com/q/2753254/1248974

Comment: How are you running your program? `..` is relative to `cwd` not to the folder where your `.py` is

Comment: Have you tried this? `filename = os.path.join( os.getcwd(), '..', 'saved_data.json' )` and `with open(filename, 'rt') as file_in:`

Comment: try `import os
cwd = os.getcwd()`  to see where exactly you are executing your code

Comment: The result you get from running os.getcwd() depends on the directory you are standing in when you are running your script. What you can also do is os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)) which gives you the absolute path of the directory of the file you are running. From that you can modify this path to match the location of your json. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3430372/how-do-i-get-the-full-path-of-the-current-files-directory

Comment: Oh, I didn’t know it mattered where you ran the script from. My thinking was that the directory I was working from was main.py’s directory.

Comment: You can play around with it if you make a simple .py that only prints os.getcwd(). Try to run the file while standing in different locations and see the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are running your program (effectively) like this:

```
python main.py
```

...then...

```
from os.path import join

with open(join(__file__, '..', 'saved_data.json')) as file_in:
  pass # process the file here
```

Thus your current working directory is irrelevant because **file** will be the absolute path to main.py

Comment: I tried this and got another FileNotFound error, but changing the path to `__file__, '..', '..', 'stored_data.json'` (adding an extra `'..'`) did the trick. It seems like files are treated in a similar way to directories.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is about how to layout the structure of your project folder. This is a very hard topic for newbies.

Keep in mind that there are a lot of possible ways and styles to do this in Python. But looking into the `setuptools` documentation today the *modern* and most recommended style is the so called _`src`-layout.

Your layout is still on its way to it and just need a bit modification.

Let's assume the *name* of your project is "`project`". This results in the name of the repository (e.g. on a git server) or the project folder. It is also the name of your *package*. But package-folder and project-folder are different things.

Modify your layout to this

```
project/
    saved_data.json
    src/
        project/
            __main__.py
            __init__.py
            resources.py
            more files...
```

I created a new sub-folder `project/src/project/` which is the package folder. The `main.py` file was moved into it and renamed to `__main__.py` (more [details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31329365/4865723)). This make the folder `project/src/project/` runable.

The content of `__main__.py` could look like this

```
from .ressources import load_json

if __name__ == '__main__':
   load_json()
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips on good file structure. I’m having a hard time running my project as a module though. I had to cd to it in order to get it to run. Will I have to do that every time I want to run it? (I was trying to do something like `python -m project/src/project`.) Also I’m still not sure what my filepath string should be.

Comment: I would recommend to "install" your project via the `--editable` option of `pip`. You can see a small and easy real life example of it in [one of my projects](https://codeberg.org/buhtz/hyperorg/src/branch/main). Please feel free to ask further (maybe in the Issue section of my project).